# Adding a "pin it" button when hover over a Colorbox image

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I am improving a wordpress blog for a client.  I have a Colorbox lightbox gallery that needs to have Pinterest "pin-it" buttons appear when you hover over the individual, full-size, images while Colorbox is running.

It seems like anyway I append a class to the full-size images in the colorbox, it doesn't change anything.  I think I am misundertanding a fundamental issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the images in a 'div' container, set the style of that div to position:relative.

Then add another div inside that container in addition to the image with position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px; display:hidden.

Then if your container div class is 'imagecontainer' and your div for Pinterest is called 'socialbuttons' then the following CSS will do the trick:

```
.imagecontainer:hover socialbuttons { display:block; }
```

That's it.

Comment: I was not specific enough, I apologize.  That would solve my problem as I explained it.  I am attempting to use a specific script, [link](http://www.uxde.net/2012/04/29/how-to-add-pinterest-button-for-images-wordpress-without-plugin/), and I need it to only apply to images inside my Colorbox lightbox, while its running....